# Spring circular dependency fails on Linux but works on Windows

Tags: java, spring

Working on a Spring Boot 1.3.3 / Spring Framework 4.2.5 project, I faced a circular dependency (ServiceA autowired in ServiceB, and ServiceB autowired in ServiceA - injection is done via constructors). I solved this problem with some refactoring to delete this circular dependency.

Meanwhile, I noticed that the code (TestNG unit tests) worked on Windows (Windows 7, Java 8), and failed on our Jenkins CI (Linux).

-> Is there any reason to explain why it worked on Windows ? I'm trying to make my Windows local builds to reflect CI builds as much as possible.

//edit -> it may be an important information: I can't give an accurate number, but ~75% of Linux builds fail and ~25% don't fail (still on Linux). There is no random condition in pom.xml, but I probably miss something...

Comment: How do you run the test on windows and on Jenkins? Do you run it via IDE or Maven? When test fails what is the reason of failing?

Comment: Try @Lazy annotation on constructor parameter.

Comment: @Serghey Bishyr: on Windows, it runs with IntelliJ or via Maven command line.

Comment: @Nick Savenia: sure, I tried it first and it worked, before trying to write a better code :)